# Unidirectional @OneToMany does not work as expected with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, nhibernate-mapping

If i use this piece of code (CASE 1 in picture):

```
@Data
@Entity
public class PostOneUni {

    @EmbeddedId //if @Id, class CompositeId must be annotated @Embeddable?
    private CompositeId id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id1"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "id2")
    })
    private Set<PostCommentUniMany> comments = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

and when execute creation of this object and add child comments, when saving to DB everything works as expected (ids on child `PostCommentUniMany` are added as expected) but changes are not propagated to java code (Object `@12081` in picture should have `id` field updated to `2` and not `null`).

In other case (CASE 2) I use this code:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class PostOneUni {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Set<PostCommentUniMany> comments = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

and as you can see from the picture, fields are also persisted to DB, and the object that was used to save state to DB is updated after save (Object `@12052` is updated to reflect `id` field to be `2` - as in DB).

[image]

How to update object `@12081` in CASE 1 to reflect DB id?

**UPDATE**

After discussion below - problem was that if `id` on entity is set manually to some value, Spring think it is not new entity and tries to do merging instead of persisting the entity.

One of "workarounds" is to set `@Version` field on `@Entity` class `PostOneUni` that will track if entity is new or not.

```
@Version
private Integer version;
```

Comment: You will need to post the code of the ID class and the code you use to create and persist these objects.

Comment: @Alan Hay - I can. Composite is just standard lombok @_Value and saving is done with Spring Data JPA repos .save(PostOneUni) method using @_Transactional.

Comment: You need to add the code not tell me about it.

Comment: @AlanHay OK, I updated with code.

Comment: The instance `comment2` and the instance `comment2` in the collection are different items in memory which is obviously not good. I would expect these to be the same instance in memory. How has this happened?

Comment: @Alan Hay - this is because I load second collection using `findById` method on repository, and that one constructs completely new objects. This should be OK. It is just this first `comment2` that has `id=null` (which is ok state, but BEFORE saving), after calling `save` on repo - hibernate should update it to `id=2` (as is case in CASE 2).

Comment: yeah, I know how it works but unfortunately cannot guess what you code is doing if you don't bother to post the relevant parts.

Comment: @AlanHay Here is link to full project (this is root test case): https://github.com/bojanv55/hi-perf-java-persistence/blob/master/src/test/java/me/vukas/hiperfjavapersistence/service/OneToManyIT.java

Comment: "that one constructs completely new objects". Assuming you have cleared 1st level cache.

Comment: If it's not the same instance then it should be:https://stackoverflow.com/a/4226961/1356423

Comment: I found out that if I manually set `ID` on `Post` object (with `post.setId(1L);`), it behaves the same as `EmbeddedId` (does not update children (comment) ids). So it must be some logic in AUTO_INCREMENT key that is forcing propagation to children IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that because you have set the ID fields manually Spring Data calls a merge operation rather than persist:

See org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) //checks if ID null {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

And the JPA spec notes that when

> **3.2.7.1 Merging Detached Entity State**
>
> • If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is
>   created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity
>   instance X'.

In your test code if you therefore do:

`post = oneToManyService.addNewPost(post);`

the identifiers are set correctly on the returned instance just as they are when you reload from the database. However, the original instances (in 'new' state)  remain unchanged i.e do not have IDs set.

Where persist is called rather than merge, then the original (same) instance is returned and the identifiers will be set correctly on this instance.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I will try this one. `JpaRepository` does not expose `persist`, so I have to check how to do this one. Isn't Spring Data smart enough to check if manually set Id is in DB and flag it as new? I also saw that there is `Version` field that can be set to make this decision.

Comment: Spring Data is making the decision in the code posted.

Comment: See here possibly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255257/1356423 Implement Persistable interface and define your own `isNew()` implementation.

Comment: Progress :) Now I have `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: me.vukas.hiperfjavapersistence.entity.relationship.onetomany.PostOneUni; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: me.vukas.hiperfjavapersistence.entity.relationship.onetomany.PostOneUni
`

Comment: OK. I can confirm this was the problem. After adding field `@Version private Integer version;` to `PostOneUni`, it works as expected. Maybe there is some other way without using Versioning?